# "No key data found" when getting PGP private key from AWS Secrets Manager

Tags: java, private-key, aws-secrets-manager, pgp

I'm having some trouble getting a decryption tool to work on production. I'm using PGPainless in Java to decrypt documents using a preset private key and key passphrase. To test locally, I'm using a custom secrets JSON file that Docker picks up. Everything, from the code to my Retool app, works great this way. (I point the app at my local Ngrok.) However, when I copy exactly the same keys/values from my local secrets to AWS Secrets Manager, the Java fails to read the private key, telling me "No key data found." I've tried a number of different ways to format the private key, specifically around the whitespace/line breaks, but nothing works.

```java
byte[] keyBytes = ourSecretsService.getPgpPrivateKey().getBytes();
String keyPassword = ourSecretsService.getPgpPrivatePassPhrase();

SOP sop = new SOPImpl();
byte[] resultBytes = sop.decrypt()
  .withKey(keyBytes)
  .withKeyPassword(keyPassword)
  .ciphertext(encryptedFileBytes)
  .toByteArrayAndResult()
  .getBytes();
```

Answer (score 0):

The key was formatted differently when it was brought in. It should be stored in AWS using `\n` for the line breaks. Then in the code, I did `replace("\\n", "\n")` before converting to bytes.